# I have written a custom function that returns two dataframes, is there anyway to use this custom function in df.apply(custumF) and get two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have written a custom function that transforms input dataframe and  returns two dataframes, is there anyway to use this custom function in

`df.apply(custumF)`

and get two output dataframes except

`df.apply(custumF[0])` and `df.apply(custumF[1])`

Answer (score 0):

No, not without changing how the `pandas.DataFrame.apply` function works.

From the documentation it states that

> Returns: Series or DataFrame

If you really wanted to you could do something like:

```py
my_two_df = lambda df, fs: (df.apply(fs[0]), df.apply(fs[1]))
```

But, I don't think this gives a better solution than just calling your function on two separate lines for readability.